# Positioning Divs using CSS (Float div below another div)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create several `div`s and lay them out onto several rows and columns. I have positioned them using `float` (for columns in same row) and `clear` to create a new row. It all works fine, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujq60xb9/)

Now, my issue is that the `div`s in my rows can be of arbitrary height and not uniform. If a particular div in my row is taller than the rest, it would create the next row with a `blank space` below the shorter divs. Is there anyway I can avoid the space and position the div just below the previous row's div?

Below is a pictorial representation of what I got and what is the expectation:

**Current layout:**

[image]

**Expected layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS way to do that is to make 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B `display: inline-block` individually. and make the bigger ones floated.

working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sdghasemi/rfdh87ec/) here.

and add some margins to undo default inline-block margins and give its parent div some `width` and `height`.

hope it helps!

Comment: This solution looks interesting, since it makes use of CSS properties to re-position (a bit hacky though!). Can you please explain me how this works? I don't seem to be able to get an hang of it

Comment: :) Actually it separates each same-size div from the bigger ones and controls the row counts with its parent width (I used a kinda limitation instead of using `clear: both` to break the line). Its also better because it doesn't force you to have just 6 divs, and you can design whatever you want!

Comment: Please provide the relevant code here rather than in a external site. Also, StackOverflow provides a fiddler for Html/JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You should use columns instead of rows.

```
<div id="customtable">
    <div id="row1">
        <div id="col1" style="width:64px; float:left;">
           <div id="row1col1" style="float:left; border:1px solid; width: 30px; height:30px">1A</div>
           <div id="row1col2" style="float:left; border:1px solid; width: 30px; height:30px">1B</div>
          <div id="row2col1" style="float:left; border:1px solid; width: 30px; height:30px">2A</div>
         <div id="row2col2" style="float:left; border:1px solid; width: 30px; height:30px">2B</div>
      </div>
    <div id="col2" style="width:40px; float:left;">
        <div id="row1col3" style="float:left; border:1px solid; width: 40px; height:40px">1C</div>   
        <div id="row2col3" style="float:left; border:1px solid; width: 40px; height:40px">2C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujq60xb9/2/)

On the other hand you can use [flexgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/)  based on css flex. However it isn't supported by IE9-

Comment: Although this works for the specific case of knowing that the last item of both rows is of a different height, it won't work in any other case.  Consider, for instance, a three row layout where 1B, 2B, and 3C are the oversized elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use a javascript plugin like [masonryjs](http://masonry.desandro.com). What masonry does is align the content for you, all you do is specify the width. The advantages include a fluid and responsive site.

```
var container = document.querySelector('#customtable');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: 30,
  itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/CucuIonel/pen/Fdiwl) that has a layout similar to what you are trying to achieve.